# Different locations for MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, database

Can I configure MySQL to store a specific database in a separate place on disk?

I still want any new databases to go to the default location, but there's a specific database that I'd like to have stored in my Dropbox folder so that it can stay synced between a few computers.

How can I do this?

Comment: Incidentally, it's possible to do this the other way around. Leave the database as it was, and symlink *to* it from Dropbox. Dropbox doesn't really understand symlinks, and will just sync them as normal.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Of course you can! You have to **grant root permisson**. Read the **ln** manual pages.

MySQL stores the database data in separated dirs in `/var/lib/mysql`. I think, at first you had to make a dir, where you want to put the selected database's files.
Grant root permisson, stop MySQL deamon:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Copy your data to your new folder:

```
# cp /var/lib/mysql/DATABASENAME /path/to/new/database/dir
```

Remove your old dir from MySQL data files: (**Warning! ALWAYS make SQL dump first!!!**)

```
# rm -R /var/lib/mysql/DATABASENAME
```

Make a symlink back to MySQL data dir: (**Pay attention! Read the man page of ln first!!!**)

```
# ln -s /full/path/to/new/database/dir /var/lib/mysql/DATABASENAME
```

After it, you are ready, start your MySQL:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Warning! If your new dir isn't write- and readable by MySQL that wouldn't work!
Example, the common problem: you place your new data dir to your home folder, your home folder is read protected by others(ex: drwxrwx--- you you yourdir).

Ask, if you want to know other things about that method!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even consider symlinks, I was too busy thinking about ways to do it inside mysql.

Comment: You'll want to edit `/etc/apparmor.d/*mysqld` to include the new directory too. Then `sudo service apparmor reload` before restarting MySQL.

Comment: @KeesCook thanks so much for the apparmor tip, that was driving me crazy!! Looks like it's better to put it in `/etc/apparmor.d/local` though (on my install there's already a usr.sbin.mysqld there), adding a single `/full/path/to/new/database/dir/** rwk,` did it for me...

Comment: Thanks so much, some details of editing the apparmor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182468/moving-mysql-innodb-database-to-separate-drive/11751680#11751680) is also useful. I was slowed down trying to put the database on a drive which does did not mount automatically at boot and needed root user to access it. Refused to work. Edited `fstab` like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup) so that that drive was mounted in the file system after bootup, now everything works.

Answer (score 3):

Please bear in mind that if you are using Ubuntu, you need also to add an entry in the AppArmour configuration file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld otherwise you will keep getting writing permission errors even though you change files and folder permissions.