# How to mount a new drive on startup

Tags: fstab

I have recently installed a new hard drive to my Ubuntu **10.0.4** box. I used System -> Administration -> Disk Utils to format the disk (ext4 file type) - but did not create a partition (is this advisable?).

I have manually mounted the drive as /mydata.

I want to have the machine automatically mount the device on startup/reboot. How may I do this?

**[[Update]]**

This is the output from running `sudo fdisk -l` on my system:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000858bf

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       59334   476595200   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           59334       60802    11789313    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           59334       60802    11789312   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 16.0 GB, 16026435072 bytes
254 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1956 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16002 * 512 = 8193024 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1        1955    15641929    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: there's a disks utility in 12.04 ... have a look you may find one in your version.  It allows you to edit mount option on a partition there's one for startup

Comment: Obtain the UUID of the disk and add it to the /etc/fstab as demonstrated in this [tutorial](https://bit.ly/2Ur9XZY).

Answer (score 127, accepted):

First of all your `/dev/sdb` isn't partitioned. I am assuming this is the disk you want to mount.

## WARNING: THIS WILL DESTROY ANY DATA ON YOUR TARGET DISK

---

Run `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`

1. Press <kbd>O</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> *(creates a new table)*
2. Press <kbd>N</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> *(creates a new partition)*
3. Press <kbd>P</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> *(makes a primary partition)*
4. Then press <kbd>1</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> *(creates it as the 1st partition)*
5. Finally, press <kbd>W</kbd> *(this will write any changes to disk)*

---

Okay now you have a partition, now you need a filesystem.

6. Run `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`
7. Now you can add it to fstab

   You need to add it to `/etc/fstab` use your favourite text editor

   **Be careful with this file as it can quite easily cause your system not to boot.**

   Add a line for the drive, the format would look like this.

   *This assumes the partition is formatted as ext4 as per mkfs above*

   ```
   #device        mountpoint             fstype    options  dump   fsck

   /dev/sdb1    /home/yourname/mydata    ext4    defaults    0    1
   ```

---

Then on the next reboot it will auto mount.

This web page has a lot of useful info on [fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the danger with editing fstab (thats why I thought I'd come in here and ask first). As it happens, my new drive is not partitioned, I formatted the entire drive using file type ext4, and the device name (obtained using Disk Utility GUI app) is /dev/sdb. Following from the syntax you gave, the new entry should be `/dev/sdb /mydata  ext4 defaults 0 1`. I want the drive to be mapped to /mydata (from the root). Is that the correct syntax to use?

Comment: No it should be /dev/sdb1 if it is the only partition on the disk. you can check with "sudo fdisk -l" this will show you the disk /dev/sdb and then its partitions so /dev/sdb1 will be your ext4, and the mount point would be "/mydata" which would mean it was a folder that already exists on the root of the drive called mydata. FYI use the existing folders /mnt/mydata or possibly/var/mydata its what they're for.

Comment: Yikes!. Thanks for the feedback. I have added the output of running `sudo fdisk -l` on my machine. Please advice how to proceed. MTIA.

Comment: I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Steve: Have you noticed that fdisk reports `Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table` in the output - should I be worried?. I remember reading somewhere that some apps may expect me to have created a partition on the disk and if they attempt to write to the disk - I'll lose the data on that disk. True?. If so, I will start from scratch again (instructions please ...). I can afford to lose the data at this stage but definitely not later on.

Comment: Yes i explain in answer..

Comment: Steve: You Sir, are a STAR!

Comment: @Shutupsquare I met a similar issue today. I did some test and I found that you don't need to create partition at all. Without any partition, you can use /dev/sdb directly in /etc/fstab file instead of /dev/sdb1

Comment: You should use `blkid` to find the uuid of the drive and use that as the filesystem. Otherwise the partition maybe moved and the incorrect device would be mounted

Comment: It worked for me, good job and nicely explained.

Comment: This actually locked me out of my Raspberry Pi root account.  Very dangerous to modify this file.

Comment: same here as @IgorG.

Comment: It's worth using `nofail` as an option so the machine still boots when the drive isn't connected.  More info in the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#External_devices).

Comment: Good answer, a recommendation is to use mount -a before restarting your machine.

Comment: for anyone who gets stucked out of its raspberry, just like Igor, Alex and me, here's a link to get things back on feet: http://clarkle.com/notes/emergecy-mode-bad-fstab/

Comment: other filesystems should have a fs_passno of 2 I think

Comment: Isn't `/dev/sdb1 /mnt/ssd    ext4    defaults    0    1` more fail proof than `/dev/sdb1    /home/yourname/mydata    ext4    defaults    0    1`?

Comment: "fsck sets the order for file system checks at boot time; For the root device it should be 1. For other partitions it should be 2, or 0 to disable checking."

Answer (score 92):

The GUI solution for me is **gnome-disks**

```
sudo gnome-disks
```

[image: gnome-disks]

Then with the configuration button you can "edit mount options", feel free to give the destination of your mount point and it will be saved into the /etc/fstab automatically
[image]

**Note:** the `nofail` option that causes the system not to hang if this mount point is not available, could be useful in case of potential unreachable filesystem on boot such as USB, NFS, etc.

Comment: This is the safest way I have come across ever. I like to be the command line ninja, but for very critical operations like this, fail safe ways are always preferred.

Comment: what is the syntax for the read-write option in ubuntu 20.04.1? i tried 'rw' but DOESNOT work. FAT32 with a single partition...

Answer (score 18):

To set the drive to mount automatically each time you boot the computer

You’ll need to edit /etc/fstab:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add this line to the end:

```
/dev/sdaX /media/mydata ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Note: Make sure to replace the X with the right value for your situation.

Or you can use Storage Device Manager, [from the software centre.](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pysdm/)

Comment: It should be noted that the /dev/hda2 in the example above can be replaced by the uuid of the device. The uuid is a long number string that identifies uniquely the hard disk. To find it, use the command "sudo blkid". It will list all drives connected on the system.

Comment: @frepie Please note, UUID is used only when Disk is GPT. Incase of MBR Disk, use /dev/sdaX .

Answer (score 9):

The fstab file lets the system know which drives to mount (or how to mount them, at least).

```
sudo edit /etc/fstab
```

then add a line like this one:

```
/dev/sdb1      /mydata   ext4   defaults   0   0
```

Of course, replace the values to suit your actual locations:

- `/dev/sdb1` should be the device and partition for the disk you want to mount.
- `/mydata` is the place where you want to mount it.
- `ext4` is the type of filesystem it's using. If you're not sure, issue the `mount` command without arguments when the drive is mounted (even if you mounted it manually), it will tell you the filesystem type. (in 12.04 you may simply type `auto` which determines the filesystem for you at launch)
- The other values (`defaults 0 0`) are OK like I show them.

If you want to learn more, you can read `man fstab`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using FAT32 or NTFS file system using the following:

For NTFS:

```
/dev/sda3   /media/entertainment    ntfs-3g rw,auto,user,fmask=0111,dmask=0000,noatime,nodiratime   0   0
/dev/sda4   /media/other    ntfs-3g rw,auto,user,fmask=0111,dmask=0000,noatime,nodiratime   0   0
```

`noatime` and `nodiratime` are some optimizations. If you want you can remove them.

For FAT32 replace `ntfs-3g` with `vfat`.

Answer (score 7):

You could do it via [/etc/fstab](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html).

For example, if you add

```
/dev/hda2   /myfiles    ext2    defaults    0    0
```

It means that the device/partition located at /dev/hda2 will be mounted to /myfiles using the file system ext2, with default mount options and no dumping and no error-checking enabled.

Answer (score 6):

**fstab** will help you for sure.

For those lazy and cautious ones who want to use a simple and self-explanatory GUI there is a tool called **Storage Device Manager (pysdm)**. The tutorial here will do basically the same as other answers in this thread suggest to do, but the tool will accomplish it with a couple of clicks and no need to enter configurations manually into fstab config file.

`sudo apt-get install pysdm`(Ubuntu) or `sudo yum install pysdm`(Fedora)

Nothing should go wrong, but just in case, backup the fstab conf: `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.old`

Now run the Storage Device Manager and select your preferred partition, click "Assistant":

[image]

PySDM assistant settings for automounting EXT4 partition:
[image]

PySDM assistant for automounting NTFS partition:
[image]

**Reboot** and see that your **drive gets automatically mounted now**.

You can learn more about assistant settings from [this article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/how-to-mount-partitions-automatically.html), as it explains the process in details and my answer is based on it.

**UPDATE:** `pysdm` has been removed from the Ubuntu archives ([AskUbuntu page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237066/where-is-the-pysdm-package)), `sudo apt-get install pysdm` does not work anymore.

> Avoid using pysdm for now.
>
> It's been removed from the Ubuntu archives for a reason:
>
> please remove Pysdm from Ubuntu repositories. It is obsolete (not updated since June 2006 !!), buggy (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pysdm) , doesn't handle UUIDs (which is now fstab standard in all supported Ubuntu versions !!!) and it has already been removed from Debian repositories.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to partition or cannot afford to, you can use udisks to mount or unmount devices or disks. The UUID method is the most stable one as other ID methods can change if you rename your label for example.

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdb
udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/70439c63-de2c-4319-a832-0dee5ea05fc5
udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-label/HDD
```

It will in fact do the same as you would do by clicking the device on nautilus.

[image: nautilus mount]

Just add it as a "startup application" to preform at login.

To unmount, (if you need to):

```
udisks --unmount /dev/sdb
```

Will do the same as clicking the unmount arrow in nautilus.

One disadvantage over the `fstab` method is the device will be mounted in `/media/disk_label` with no option to choose another mount-point.

One advantage is you do not need root access to mount or unmount the drive.

More info over different methods of auto-mounting : [AutomaticallyMountPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)