# From /media/blabla to media/my_name/blabla

Tags: mount, ntfs, disk, fstab, remapping

I have a ntfs disk which used to get mapped to `media/A6505A54505A2B11_/`. There was also a directory `media/A6505A54505A2B11/`.

Then all of a sudden it started to get mapped to `media/my_name/A6505A54505A2B11/`. The directories  `media/A6505A54505A2B11/` and  `media/A6505A54505A2B11_/` still exist but I have 'access denied' whenever I want to browse them.

What happened and how do I make it sure that this disk will be mapped only to the certain directory?

Comment: In the newer versions of Ubuntu the drives get mounted according to your name, and thus only you can read/write to them. Try using `gksudo nautilus` from ALT+F2. That will open up a root explorer that you can use to view what is in side of media/A6505A54505A2B11_/. If it is empty (be sure to check for hidden folders/files with CTRL+H), you can delete it. It is most likely just an old mount point that isn't used anymore.

Comment: Do you have any objections to mounting them to /media/name/drive? If you do want them to be mounted to a different point then you can edit the fstab, I will post an answer soon explaining how to do that.

Comment: @DaboRoss after rebooting the computer, it again point the old location without user name.

Comment: Do you have a fstab entry for the device?

Comment: @DaboRoss Now - yes, but when it happened I didn't have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new versions of Ubuntu, the mounting points also use the **username**, so for example, my user is cyrex and my previous mount point was `/media/xtreme`. It now has become `/media/cyrex/xtreme`. If you want to force the system to mount that specific partition to your previous place then I recommend reading answers like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup/154183#154183) which mention editing the `fstab` file and adding the appropriate information to mount a partition in a specific place.

I recommend consulting the manual: `man fstab`.

An example (Do not apply this) would be:

```
   /dev/sdb1      /media/A6505A54505A2B11   ext4   defaults   0   0
```

This would mount the `sdb1` device in `/media/A6505A54505A2B11` with several parameters like assuming it has an ext4 filesystem.

Comment: after rebooting the computer, it again point the old location without user name.