# Mount Drive at Start-up but MySQL can't see it

Tags: mount, mysql, automount

I'm trying to automount my drive using the following command in startup applications:

```
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sdd1
```

However, MySQL fails to start when I mount the disk. On the contrary, if I click on the drive via the GUI, MySQL will load normally.

What is going on here? Why won't MySQL recognize the mounted drive when mounted with the command I provided?

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527), try it see if it helps.

Comment: @Mitch I tried that, and all of the drives have the automount turned on but they still don't mount when I start-up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup), see if it works.