# Mounting another hard drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, automount

I've just set up my new PC and I've got an SSD that I installed Trusty Tahr on (and also Win8, but that doesn't really matter I guess).

I've got another HD that I want to use for data (pictures, movies and stuff). When I first booted up Ubuntu, the HD was already mounted at /media/myusername/Data ("Data" is the volume description I used when formatting it). I immediately started moving some data around and created some symlinks to it.

However, now that I rebooted, all my symlinks are broken because `/media/myusername/Data` is now suddenly mounted as `root`. It is however also mounted as `myusername` under `/media/myusername/Data1`:

```
myusername@myusername-ubuntu:~$ ls -l /media/myusername
total 8
drwx------ 2 root  root  4096 Apr 24 18:40 Data
drwx------ 1 myusername myusername 4096 Apr 24 16:44 Data1
```

I don't actually want it to be mounted as root ever, how can I change that?

Comment: See [Is there a program to mount all my drives automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically) and [How to mount a new drive on startup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup)

Answer (score 0):

the mount command need to be executed every time you reboot your system but to avoid that and to do automatic mount at each reboot simply edit /etc/rc.local file and add the mount command in a new line in it then save and exit after that you may try to reboot your system to check if the mount works or not.

if you didn't execute the command and added it only to /etc/rc.local file you wont find the mount on. the mount only will work if u execute the command and the line in /etc/rc.local will work after rebooting also.

after all that change the symbolic links back to your desire and i think it will work properly at each restart.