# Desktop Shortcut Won't Work after Reboot

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed in a dual boot along with Windows 8.

When I create a desktop shortcut for a folder on a windows partition in Ubuntu using "Make a link and move it to the desktop", it won't work after I reboot.

It tells me `"the link is broken, move it to trash?"`.

I searched for similar problems but the proposed solutions didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! What program are you making a link to?

Comment: Is it a link to a Windows partition?

Comment: It's not a program , it's a folder on a windows partition

Comment: /etc/fstab. Ask me more if you need directions.

Comment: Guys I tried to auto mount the disk or manually mount it, But still I can't use the shortcut after a reboot ... any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since windows partitions are in NTFS file system type and they are not already auto-mount after login and when you mount them for this time and make form them a link, but after next reboot they are not mounted and Ubuntu not detect them at startup, so you will see error when you want to use that links:

```
"the link is broken, move it to trash?"
```

solutions:

1. Mount those partition after each login manually and then use created link form them.
2. Make them as auto-mount after next login and after system starts by following these links:

[How to mount a new drive on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup)

[Is there a program to mount all of my drives automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically)

**3. tested solution:** Type "Disks" in dash and hit enter to open that.

[image]

- Select your partition that you created a link from it(**point 1**)
- Click on "More Actions" (gear icon **point 2**)
- Select "Edit Mount Options..." (**point 3**)

this window will open:

[image]

- Drag "On/Off" slider to left side to make it "Off" (**point 4**)
- Checked "Mount at startup" check box (**point 5**)
- Now click "Close" and also close "Disks" utility.

Test step: Reboot your system and check, you will not see any more that error.

Cool!

Comment: The problem remains even after I mount the drive and still I can't use the shortcut , I don't know how to prove this ?! any solutions ?

Comment: @user2136465 wait for check that for my self...

Comment: +1 @user2136465 Ok you are right, after next reboot not working, wait for finding solution...

Comment: @user2136465 Problem solved. check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Buddy It worked , But I just wanna tell ubuntu developers this should be something already existing in the os !!!

Comment: Thank you. I already gave you a link (second link in second solution) :)