# Help in Ubuntu installation

Tags: drivers

I am new to Ubuntu and my question is how to find the E,D or F drives in my system am not getting those drives it shows only has computer.

Comment: Clicking on partition icon in nautilus will automatically mount that partition.But if you want these to automount during boot ,in this case, it  might be helpful for you.[How to mount a new drive on startup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup)

Comment: In Ubuntu, drives don't get drive letters but get mounted under /media/your_username/drive_label.

Answer (score 2):

By default in Ubuntu you don't have many partition but one single partition which you see as computer to get different partition you have to manually configure during installation or using live bootable Linux .