# Why are my ubuntu partitions mounted somewhere else?

Tags: partitioning, mount, compiling, c++

If you refer to my other posts, I am trying to use **g++** and in order to compile a *.cpp* file I'll have to refer to it with the drive name:

```
g++ /media/drivename/filename.cpp
```

The problem is with the file path, as you see the drives are named so ridiculously with some random number group. I can't just type in

```
g++ /media/123414 14124 14 1/filename.cpp
```

I tried relabelling the partitions and turns out you don't refer to them with their labels but with their names and these names are based on where the drives are **MOUNTED**. As you can see in the below picture, these are mounted at this ridiculous location `/whateverucallit`. This is frustrating. I just switched to Ubuntu, and I'm having a really hard time here.

[image: Example]

The partitions were created after the ubuntu was installed and they were created with GParted. I have looked at other threads telling you to edit your `etc/fstab` there is no `fstab` folder there except a `fstab.d` folder and that too: an empty one.

Okay, my bad. It was talking about the `fstab` file. There is one here are the contents of the file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=956d7e6e-6935-4de9-80ec-4e4f80a510db /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=b6dea36c-6e78-46c4-a566-9a850ddd2c9c none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Turns out `fstab` doesn't even mention the two newly created partitions. What now?.

UPDATE:

I added the following lines in `fstab` but since they did nothing, I've commented them out.

```
#device        mountpoint             fstype    options  dump   fsck

#/dev/sda3    /home/robbino/driv1    ext3    defaults    0    1
#/dev/sda4    /home/robbino/driv2    ext3    defaults    0    1
```

Here's the `sudo fdisk-l` output

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001ec87

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   206092287   103045120   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       617037822   625141759     4051969    5  Extended
/dev/sda3       206092288   415674367   104791040   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       415674368   617035775   100680704   83  Linux
/dev/sda5       617037824   625141759     4051968   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mount a new drive on startup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup)

Comment: Not really, it's not about mounting it up on startup as mine are always mounted on startup. Just the mount location that needs to be modified. I could just change in fstab if it was mentioned in it

Comment: It's because it _isn't_ mounted in fstab that Ubuntu is mounting it in /media.

Comment: Will the following lines do?

#device        mountpoint             fstype    options  dump   fsck

/dev/sda3    /home/robbino/drivex    ext3    defaults    0    1
/dev/sda4    /home/robbino/drivey    ext3    defaults    0    1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo blkid
```

Find and copy needed `uuid` to reproduce it in `fstab` then run:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab
```

add to the end lines like this (e.g.):

```
#My-Partition
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /media/Robbino1              ext3
defaults 0 1
```

Where `xxxxxxxxxx` is `/dev/sda` *uuid* that you copied, then reboot.

You can also manually change permissions (e.g.):

```
rw,auto,user,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=1000,uid=1000 0 0
```

More detailed on mounting options [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Comment: Tried exactly what you told and on restart it said
"Serious errors detected while looking for /media/robbino1" press i to skip mounting"

Now, the devices aren't mounted at all. I'll go comment out those lines

Comment: The following lines are the ones I'm commenting out at this instant.

UUID=ae5bdc4c-586f-42de-b43c-94f7deedcb02 /media/Robbino1 ext3 defaults 0 1

UUID=ae5bdc4c-586f-42de-b43c-94f7deedcb02 /media/Robbino2 ext3 defaults 0 1

Comment: It worked. But now on restart it says 
"error mounting /etc/fstab/."

Comment: It worked! Thank you!! There was this 'w' character in the beginning of file that must've been a typo. I deleted it and restarted. Worked like a charm. THANK YOU,DUDE! THANKS A LOT! *brotherly hugs keeping crotch 42 km away*

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked for you.