# How to automount cardreader on startup?

Tags: mount, flash, fstab, fat32

I have SD cardreader in my netbook, and it is not automatically mounted on startup. If I disable default settings in gnome-disks and check mount automatically, I will get error

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1: Command-line `mount "/media/janet/69eb572e-8b94-44a1-9682-b6ea4ee9ac9b"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so
```

in the next monut.

But I solved it changing `x-gvfs-show` to `comment=x-gvfs-show`. Now I can't write on my SD card. How to mount it correctly? Maybe there is an option to mount it on startup? But how to do it to make it available writeable for user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mount a new drive on startup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup)

Comment: You will only be able to mount your card reader at startup if it has media in the slot, further using the UUID will only work if the media is unchanged. Swapping in a different card will change that so you would likely be better off mounting with the /dev/sdXY designation.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is this line in /etc/fstab

```
UUID=C906-C3E4 /mnt/C906-C3E4 vfat suid,dev,exec,auto,async,rw,user,uid=1000,gid=1000,comment=x-gvfs-show,comment=x-gvfs-name=CardReader 0 0
```

Comment: You will make your system pause on boot if your card will be unplugged, thus you should change option `auto` to `noauto` and mount it later on, maybe in `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: @madneon The problem is that if it won't be mounted automaticly - after resume from suspend I will be asked to enter root password to mount it. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Did you tried with `rc.local`?

Comment: @madneon Yes. There are problems with dispalying it in user interface and others. Is there a way to do it in user's autostart? Something like open SD card with nautilus and close nautilus. The card now is mounted, but disabled. Don't know command how to enable it...

Comment: What problems are there? With permissions?

Comment: @madneon Yes, but I have just dealed with them: I mount it to directory with chmod 700 and the ownership of my user and with options like in my answer. Now I don't know how to make SD card be displayed in user interface (comment=x-gvds-show doesn't work). And do I need root rights to unmount it?