# Full disk encryption on multiple drives; ext4 and GPT partition table; enter only 1 key

Tags: encryption, ext4

I'm looking for a tutorial (with clear steps) similar to the following article, but using ext4 and GPT partition tables.

[Full disk encryption with Btrfs and multiple drives in Ubuntu · Bryce Nyeggen's blog](http://nyeggen.com/post/2014-04-05-full-disk-encryption-with-btrfs-and-multiple-drives-in-ubuntu/)

I will be doing a new installation of 14.04 LTS on brand new disks. I will be upgrading to 16.04 very soon.

I have an SSD and HDD. Both should be fully encrypted. Both should be accessible after entering a single passphrase on bootup. (A key on a USB stick would be acceptable too.)

The SSD will hold these partitions:

/boot (I assume unencrypted)
/ (root)
/home
and all the usual directories in the Linux file system

The HDD will be mainly for pictures, audio, video, .deb files, zipped files, backups, etc.

Comment: Did you manage to install and configure your system according to your wish? If yes, how? I would like to do the same.

Comment: Yes, I eventually did. But that was more than 7 years ago. I no longer use Ubuntu  or ext4 on the desktop. I'm running Arch Linux and btrfs now. I would suggest you follow the Arch wiki for dm-crypt if you are interested. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt

I am running btrfs, dm-crypt and multiple drives on several Arch devices and it works great.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! 7 years ago, your post was in 2016? ;) 
How did you do it then?
Did you manage to (or do you still) have /home on the SSD and the bigger files of home on a HDD? If yes, how did you configure it? Symlink? Cache? Thanks again!

Comment: @Filbuntu Sorry, I thought this post was from 2012. I never did complete this task on Ubuntu. But I am doing something very similar on Arch with BTRFS. I used the Arch Wiki for the entire setup.

Comment: @Filbuntu For the large files, I simply mount the HDD to a directory in my /home.

Comment: Thanks again for writing! Quick question: How do you mount the HDD content to your /home. As you can see I am new this part of Linux.

Comment: @Filbuntu If you are new, maybe don't try full disk encryption yet. As far as mounting, that's easy. I partition and format the larger HDD. Then I make an /etc/fstab entry where the directories on that device are mounted where I want them to be mounted under my home folder. For example, see https://askubuntu.com/a/154184/36661

Comment: Thank you so much again! I will look into the details. I am not that new to Linux (about 10 years) and I have always fully encrypted the disk but I am new to a computer with two disks and having an SSD. That is why I am really grateful for any help!