# Can I mount a ext4 partition to "/" partition?

Tags: 14.04, mount

Yesterday, I create a ext4 partition from windows partition. And now, I want to auto mount this on startup. But I am having some problems:

[image: error when mount partition]

Can I choose "/" to mount point?
Here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=77d02065-0f94-4f21-b45e-29bf7246fcf1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c238f504-d982-476b-bff3-c43a659d30d8 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01CFEE2BD2CC9120 /mnt/01CFEE2BD2CC9120 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01CFEE2BD5542660 /mnt/01CFEE2BD5542660 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/94D25E83D25E6A0E /mnt/94D25E83D25E6A0E auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=cf7e45fc-e864-4ed9-a579-ac15c557960a /mnt/Leanr ext4 defaults 0 1
```

Comment: Please read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-system.htm --- you can't mount your new disk on top of the root filesystem. **After** having read and understood that, you can find the solution in http://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup