# How to assign a UUID to a hard drive?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 on an Acer Aspire VN7-792G that has a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. The laptop was preinstalled with Windows 10, which I removed using the diskpart utility and clean (for the SSD) or clean all (for the HDD) commands.

The HDD can be found from the terminal with the `fdisk -l` command, but is not shown on the Launcher or in the "computer" window.

I'm guessing that the first stage to correcting this is to assign the HDD (disk `/dev/sdb`) a UUID, as it does not currently appear to have one.

`fdisk -l` and `blkid` results:

[image: results of fdisk-l and blkid]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64460/83684. This answer helps, It's partitions that have UUIDs rather than disks.

Comment: This should guide you through making a partition table, a new partition and putting a filesystem on the new partition, using `fdisk`. http://askubuntu.com/a/154184/320386

Answer (score 3):

Linux systems don't mount hard drives, they mount *filesystems* that live inside partitions or logical volumes on those drives.

In the case of ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems, you can change the UUID using the `tune2fs` command. From `man tune2fs`:

```
-U UUID
       Set the universally unique identifier (UUID) of  the  filesystem
       to UUID.  The format of the UUID is a series of hex digits sepa‐
       rated          by          hyphens,          like          this:
       "c1b9d5a2-f162-11cf-9ece-0020afc76f16".   The UUID parameter may
       also be one of the following:

             clear  clear the filesystem UUID

             random generate a new randomly-generated UUID

             time   generate a new time-based UUID

       The UUID may be used by  mount(8),  fsck(8),  and  /etc/fstab(5)
       (and possibly others) by specifying UUID=uuid instead of a block
       special device name like /dev/hda1.
```

There may be equivalent commands for other filesystems.

However, based on your `fdisk` output, it looks like `/dev/sdb` is a bare unformatted disk that simply has no recognizable partition(s) or filesystem(s) defined on it.

Answer (score -1):

UUID can't be assigned manually, as far as I know.  It's generated algorithmically during a format, to ensure it's globally unique, and being able to change it to an arbitrary value would allow duplications.

Editing `/etc/fstab` can tell the OS to automatically mount a drive during startup.  This preferably uses UUID to identify the drive.  The existing UUID can be found with `blkid` or by looking in a partition editor (gparted or equivalent).

If the HDD doesn't show in `blkid` or in a partition manager, check that the data and power cables are connected to the drive, and motherboard as appropriate.

Comment: The last section is not true, blkid will work on unmounted partitions.

Comment: ext2/3/4 filesystem UUIDs can be modified using the `tune2fs` command (this is handy for *de*-duplication e.g. if you've cloned a partition and need to mount both clones on the same system)

Comment: @steeldriver  That should be its own answer.  I wasn't aware of that command (I'm mostly a GUI user), and it does exactly what the questioner was asking, presuming his HDD has the right filesystem.

Comment: @ZeissIkon OK let's see... I have a feeling this is going to turn out to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks, the 1Tb drive is now shown on the launcher and as a locked folder in my home folder.

Comment: Thanks, the 1Tb drive is now shown on the launcher and as a locked folder called "files" in my home folder.  I edited the fstab file by typing gksudo gedit in the terminal, and giving the location of the disk as /home/roger/files.  However, when I save to the HDD, an error message arises (for a libreoffice spreadsheet file in this case): "Error saving the document Untitled1:
/home/roger/files/Untitled 1.ods does not exist."  When I save to the home/roger/Documents folder the file is saved normally.  I take it there are further steps to allow my document and other files to be saved to the HDD?