# Mount disk C automatically when I load Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, windows, mate, ubuntu-mate

my situation is, I have dual boot of windows 10 home 64 bits and ubuntu mate 18.04 64 bits, when I am in ubuntu I want to access my windows files, and I have to go to the file explorer, then I made a link (shortcut) ) from my document folder in windows to my desktop in ubuntu, but every time I turn on my laptop and access ubuntu this folder comes out in gray, and it is only enabled when I load disk C from the file browser, when I do this the folder is enabled and additionally the icon of my HDD appears on the ubuntu desktop, I think that what I do is mount the disk C, but how do I mount it automatically just enter ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fstab` to automount your additional storage devices.
this post will give you some guidance [How to mount a new drive on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup)